# How can I eliminate a specific value in a column in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that I would like to eliminate specific values from. How can I delete a specific value from the column in Python? (While keeping the other values). Below is the example.

"Campaign"
1
1
2
2
3
3

How could I delete the records containing "3" ?

Hoping for some general support!

Answer (score 0):

Advice: put your code in your question and put what your got.
Below answer your question:
Example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

After that you will see:

[image: df]

and you can delete, using condition:

```
df = df[df.col1<2]
```

You will get:
[image: df]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop` or `loc` function. An example is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], 
    index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 
    columns=['A', 'B', 'Campaign']
)
value_to_eliminate = 3

# Option 1 drop
df = df.drop(df[df['Campaign'] == value_to_eliminate].index)

# Option 2 loc
df = df.loc[df['Campaign'] != value_to_eliminate]
```